# How to replace all Inf values in a cell array with NaN?

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a *2*-by-*54* cell array in Matlab. Occasionally, the second row contains some `Inf` values. I'd like to convert all `Inf` values to `NaN` values and tried using this code:

```
dataC(cellfun(@isinf, dataC, 'UniformOutput', false)) = {NaN};
```

where `dataC` is my cell array.

However, when doing that I get the following error:

> Error using subsindex
>
> Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'cell'.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: *Occasionally, the second row contains some `Inf` values* - do you mean the second row of `dataC` or the second row of `dataC{k}`? i.e. do all the elements of `dataC` just contain scalars?

Comment: And wouldn't it be nice if MathWorks woke up and provided a "NA" value the way `R` , and even Excel, do?

Answer (score 3):

To use the **approach you proposed in the question**, remove the `UniformOutput`-property, this way a logical index is returned and the elements can be addressed directly. This works only when the cell content is scalar!

```
dataC(cellfun(@isinf, dataC)) = {NaN};
```

**Edit:** Thanks *@Luis Mendo* for mentioning, that the use of `find` is not needed here. My original solution has been `dataC(find(cellfun(@isinf,dataC))) = {NaN}` and used the unnecessary `find` in the addressing of `dataC`.

In case you have **arrays in the cells**, use the following approach: Write your own function and provide it as a function handle. In the following code I implemented the function `replaceInf` to do the replacement.

```
function demo
    dataC = ones(2,4);         % generate example data
    dataC = num2cell(dataC);   % convert data to cell array
    dataC{2,3} = Inf;          % assign an Inf value
    dataC{1,2} = [1 2 Inf 3]   % add an array to cell
    dataC{1,2}                 % show the cell

    dataC = cellfun(@replaceInf, dataC, 'UniformOutput', false)
    dataC{1,2}                 % show the array in the cell

end

function out = replaceInf(in)
    in(isinf(in)) = NaN;
    out = in;
end
```

This gives the following output:

```
dataC = 
    [1]    [1x4 double]    [  1]    [1]
    [1]    [         1]    [Inf]    [1]
ans =
     1     2   Inf     3
dataC = 
    [1]    [1x4 double]    [  1]    [1]
    [1]    [         1]    [NaN]    [1]
ans =
     1     2   NaN     3
```

Comment: I don't think that this will work if the cells contain anything besides scalars. What if you mean `dataC{1,2} = [4, 3; Inf, -1]`?

Comment: The OP wants to write {NaN} to the cell, so I assume he has no arrays in the cells.

Comment: I understood the question differently where second row meant second row per cell. Otherwise why on earth would this be a cell array?

Comment: @Dan I edited my post to include a solution for arrays in the cells.

Comment: @Luis Mendo: I included and honoured your remark :)  Feel free to make further adjustments in case you are not completely happy with what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you don't just have scalars in each cell? Otherwise why are you using a cell array at all?

In order to use `cellfun` you need to convert `Inf` to `NaN` but do so *without* using the assignment operator (i.e. `=`).

If you add `NaN` to `Inf` it returns `NaN` so my strategy is to create a matrix with `NaN` where you have `Inf` and `0` otherwise. `isinf` finds the `Inf` elements but unfortunately `0*NaN` is `NaN` so you can't just add `isnan(...).*NaN`. However, `0/0` is indeterminate which Matlab returns `NaN` for and `0/1` is zero hence `0./~isnan(...)` returns what we need. Putting it all together:

```
cellfun(@(x)(x + 0./~isinf(x)), dataC, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

I think this will break if you have cells within cells though...